# Nginx holding page without rewriting images

Tags: nginx

I am trying to set up a holding page for a WordPress site on Nginx. The holding page already existed but the site used to be on an Apache server before we moved it over.

I can get it to redirect to the holding page if maintenance mode is enabled, but the `holding.png` image does not display. Here is my Nginx code:

```
server {
        # Set to on to enable holding page
        set $maintenance off;

        if ($maintenance = on) {
                rewrite ^(.*)$ /holding.html break;
        }
}
```

The holding image is located in the root of the project, just like the holding page HTML file.

Comment: Well, in order to fetch your image a request to your server is made. And what does that server send? Right... You might want to extend your check ````$maintenance = on```` to exclude the request to your image.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, I have almost no experience with Nginx, but how would I do that? I've tried Googling it but all the results seem to talk about setting up a location rather than putting something like that in an if statement

Comment: It depends on what your config looks like. Is the above file all of your Nginx configuration or do you have some locations blocks in it as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I would make Nginx send a 503 (Service Unavailable) HTTP response code while in maintenance mode. This prevents search engines from indexing your maintenance page while being offline.

Second, I would put all of the static assets for the maintenance page in a separate directory (e.g. maintenance_files) so that they are nicely coupled together and can be easily excluded from the rewrite.

Also, I would want to have a way to exclude some people so that they are able to do their maintenance tasks. This can be done by IP or by checking for a cookie. You could then set/unset the cookie using a piece of javascript that you paste into your browser inspector.

```
server {
  error_page 503 @maintenance;

  # Set to 1 to enable holding page
  set $maintenance 0;

  # Always allow access for clients that have the 'maintainer' cookie set
  if ($http_cookie ~* "maintainer") {
    set $maintenance 0;
  }

  location / {
    if ($maintenance) {
      return 503;
    }
  }

  location @maintenance {
    # You might want to use a different document root for the maintenance
    # files so you can freely move and shuffle in the default document root
    # during maintenance. 
    #root /var/www/maintenance/;

    if ($uri !~ ^/maintenance_files/) {
      rewrite ^(.*)$ /holding.html break;
    }
  }
}
```

In order to get maintenance access, paste this in your browser inspector:

```
document.cookie="maintainer=1";
```

To remove that cookie:

```
document.cookie = "maintainer=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC";
```

Alternatively, instead of having a variable `$maintenance` that you set to *1*, you could check for a file being present on disk. This way you wouldn't have to reload your Nginx configuration in order to put your site in maintenance mode. However, you would add an addition disk lookup on each request which might be a reason to choose for your option. In that case, run the following command after changing the $maintenance value:

```
sudo service nginx force-reload
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks a lot! I couldn't get the cookie thing to work, though. It started saying that $maintenance wasn't a valid parameter for the if statement, but aside from that this was exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Glad to be of any help. I rewrote my answer to what I ended up with after testing and tweaking it on my own environment.